# how to get current variable value in loop (xsl)?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to add '`,`' only when it's needed

I check `<xsl:when test="$myvar!=''">` so it will not be like:

```
,one,two,three
```

but will be 
`one,two,three` instead

but it says

> Variable $myvar has not been declared;

```
<xsl:variable name="myvar">
    <xsl:for-each select="$header/Packaging[@type='european']/UPCPackagingLevelCode">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$myvar!=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',.)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed trying to use a variable before it is has been declared. You are referring to **$myVar** in the body of the variable declaration. **$myVar** won't actually be declared until after the final closing **xsl:variable**

In this case, what you need to solve your problem is make use of the **position** function to determine if you are positioned on the first **UPCPackagingLevelCode** element.

So, instead of doing this....

```
<xsl:when test="$myvar!=''">
```

Do this...

```
<xsl:when test="position() > 1">
```

In fact, you could slightly simplify this, to use **xsl:if** instead of **xsl:choose**

```
<xsl:if test="position() > 1">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="." />
```

And if you were using XSLT2.0, you could simplify the whole thing to just this

```
<xsl:variable name="myvar">
   <xsl:value-of select="$header/Packaging[@type='european']/UPCPackagingLevelCode"
       separator="," />
</xsl:variable>
```